# getting encrypted data while recording through JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

While recording my business application i am getting below as response data. How to change this into regular html Response.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfL3H.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [binary data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) to me, any chance you're downloading a file?

If yes, you can

1. Store it to hard drive for later re-use using [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file)
2. Validate the response data by ticking `Save response as MD5 hash` box on "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler and using [MD5Hex Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion)
3. If the file is in one of [Apache Tika supported formats](https://www.javatpoint.com/apache-tika-supported-formats) you can add [tika-app.jar](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), restart JMeter to pick the .jar up and use `Document` mode of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener for viewing the file contents:

   [image]

   check out [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter/) article for more information

---

If the data is really "encoded" you need to talk to the application developers to determine the algorithm and requirements for the decoding